# HP Fortify - Software security center, Audit Issues button is not enabled

Tags: fortify, securitycenter

I have uploaded the reports from HP SCA (Audit workbench) to Software Security centre, I am not able to "Audit Issues" the button is de-active. I have tried every possible option. 
1. User with which i am log in as Admin (so no rights issue). However to be on safe side i have created a user and checked with other roles (Manager, Security Lead, Security Champs etc) and proper access permissions as well.

2. In artifacts i have upload one scan and it shows blue button of (SCA) coloumn on.

Any suggestions/Thoughts would be helpful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhSm4.png)

Comment: Check your fortify.license file for a line that says something like CollabMod. A very long time ago the ability to audit issues in SSC was an add on. You can email fortifytechsupport@hpe.com and they can verify your license is correct.

Comment: This worked Eric :) Its license shows CollabMod was expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your license it would be expired. As i have seen most of the time if license are expired this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please go to Artifacts tab on ssc project and see of fpr file is uploaded correctly or waiting for approval ?

usually SSC ask for approval when

1. You're uploading fpr file generated with the scan engine version lower that the ssc server version
2. If you have already previous fpr is uploaded and new fpr file code has more than 10% difference

if that is so that you have to just approve the uploaded artifacts and add comment for approval.

Answer to you second question if you see blue button under sca column means your fpr is uploaded & processed successfully

Hope this helps ....

Comment: Hi Suman - Thanks for such a prompt reply.

1. In Artifacts i have approved it already but still "Audit issues" is disabled. 
2. No its new project, i have just created for testing purposes. Below are the steps that i have followed 
1. Scan the code.
2. Uploaded the fpr file on SSC (In a newly created project, where Admin already have all permissions (However to ensure i have given the most needed roles ( Manager, Security Lead, Security Champs etc) as well. 
3. Then that SCA coloumn shows full blue button (Surety that code is uploaded successfully) 

but STILL the "Audit Issue" is disabled.